# Помогите усовершенствовать скрипт

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт:

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.flash').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

Как убрать анимацию, чтоб разворачивалась к примеру как на pikabu. ru. И прописать к .flash еще два класса, чтобы выполнялось и для них тоже самое действие. И если entry развернут - применить к flash и entry css ?

Comment: >> как на pikabu. ru

минут 5 искал какую же всётаки анимацию имел ввиду ТС, не понял..

Comment: @shurik, хорошо, как сделать если entry развернут - применить к flash и entry css ?

Comment: >> применить к flash и entry css ?
Действие одно или разные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > [[@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)](/users/1182/shurik), хорошо, как сделать если entry развернут - применить к flash и entry css ?

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.flash').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName != 'A') {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow", function () {
            if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('.flash').addClass('class1').addClass('class2');
                $('.entry').addClass('class1').addClass('class2');
            } else {
                $('.flash').removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
                $('.entry').removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
            }
        });
    }
});
```